# Connect to Redis sentinel using the StackExchange.Redis ConnectionMultiplexer instead of the BookSleeve ConnectionUtils

Tags: c#, redis, booksleeve, stackexchange.redis

How can I connect to Redis sentinel using the StackExchange.Redis ConnectionMultiplexer instead of the BookSleeve ConnectionUtils.

I am currently using BookSleeve:

`ConnectionUtils.Connect("127.0.0.1:26379,serviceName=mymaster");`

I tried to replace it with StackExchange.Redis:
`ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("127.0.0.1:26379,serviceName=mymaster");`

but it's not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: This feature (sentinel service discovery) has not yet been migrated; however, the pieces are all in place so this should be available very soon

Comment: @MarcGravell, any update on this feature?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a real answer but I hope to help you, I use REDIS Sentinel with [ServiceStack.Redis](https://servicestack.net/redis), I didn't found a solution with the free StackExchange.Redis to use Sentinel.
This is my code with ServiceStack:

```
    using ServiceStack.Redis;

    private static IRedisClientsManager GetRedisSentinel()
    {
        IRedisClientsManager redisManager = null;

        try
        {
            List<string> listSentinels = new List<string>();
            listSentinels.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedisDB1"]);
            listSentinels.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedisDB2"]);
            listSentinels.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedisDB3"]);
            listSentinels.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedisDB4"]);

            RedisSentinel redisSentinel = new RedisSentinel(listSentinels, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedisMaster"]);
            redisSentinel.SentinelWorkerConnectTimeoutMs = 500;
            redisManager = redisSentinel.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.Trace(ex, "Error Redis Connection: " + ex.Message);
        }

        return redisManager;
    }

    public static object GetRedisCache<T>(string key)
    {
        object myObject = null;

        //naming convention [PLATFORM]:[PROJECT]:[FUNCTION]:[PARAMETERS…]
        string redisKey = string.Format("WEB:MyProject:{0}:{1}", typeof(T), key);


        //Open Redis
        IRedisClientsManager redisManager = GetRedisSentinel();
        if (redisManager != null)
        {
            try
            {
                using (RedisClient redis = (RedisClient)redisManager.GetClient())
                {
                    //Redis and Object connection
                    var redisGateways = redis.As<T>();

                    //Check if the object exists with the key
                    myObject = redisGateways.GetValue(redisKey);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.Trace(ex, "Error Get In Redis: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        return myObject;
    }

    public static void SaveRedisCache<T>(object myObject, string key, DateTime? expireDateTime = null)
    {
        if (expireDateTime == null)
            expireDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20);

        //naming convention [PLATFORM]:[PROJECT]:[FUNCTION]:[PARAMETERS…]
        string redisKey = string.Format("WEB:MyProject:{0}:{1}", typeof(T), key);

        if (myObject != null)
        {
            //Open Redis
            IRedisClientsManager redisManager = GetRedisSentinel();
            if (redisManager != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (RedisClient redis = (RedisClient)redisManager.GetClient())
                    {
                        //Redis and Object connection
                        var redisGateways = redis.As<T>();

                        //Store in Redis and put 20 minutes as expire
                        bool isExists = redisGateways.SetEntryIfNotExists(redisKey, (T)myObject);
                        if (isExists)
                            redisGateways.ExpireEntryAt(redisKey, (DateTime)expireDateTime);
                        else
                            redisGateways.SetEntry(redisKey, (T)myObject); //Update
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _log.Trace(ex, "Error Save In Redis: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void EraseRedisCache<T>(string key)
    {
        //naming convention [PLATFORM]:[PROJECT]:[FUNCTION]:[PARAMETERS…]
        string redisKey = string.Format("WEB:MyProject:{0}:{1}", typeof(T), key);

        //Open Redis
        IRedisClientsManager redisManager = GetRedisSentinel();
        if (redisManager != null)
        {
            try
            {
                using (RedisClient redis = (RedisClient)redisManager.GetClient())
                {
                    //Redis and Object connection
                    var redisGateways = redis.As<T>();

                    redisGateways.RemoveEntry(redisKey);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.Trace(ex, "Error Remove In Redis: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```